# What does the conversation mean?

Tags: dialogue, source-code

In Source Code, I did not get the meaning of a conversation between Capt. and Christina in the train. It was between roughly 00:42:00-00:43:00

The conversation was as follows:

```
Capt- Okay. Christina? Um...I've been having these dreams lately. Really vivid. 
      And you've been in them.
Christina- Really?
Capt- What? Oh. No. Not like that. Not that I wouldn't. I...It's just...Um..
```

So what was it that he wanted to say, but could not complete and why Christina left him without listening to him completely. I could not get that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He was talking about the entire source code project (getting in someone else's body) and trying to explain to her what was really going on to make her understand/help him. As he realizes his actions might seem strange, he tries to convince her to go with it.

She dismisses it as it doesn't seem important (only dreams) and flirts with him

Answer (score 13):

I'm rather surprised that both previous answers completely miss the meaning of that conversation.

"I had a vivid dream about you" often means a sexual dream, which is why she flirtingly responded with a loaded "really?" and he began bumbling to explain that he wasn't dreaming about her naked and/or dreaming about the two of them making the Beast With Two Backs.

Comment: I was just about to write the same thing.  The accepted answer is off the mark, this is the correct answer.

Comment: People downvoting, feel free to share why, since this is ***exactly*** what that conversation is about.

Comment: That whole "Not like that.  Not that I wouldn't..." part is a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 0):

Right in the beginning they show random images of what Colter sees through the process of entering and exiting the Source Code program.

These images:

[image]
[image]

These doesn't seem to be a memory from Colter's past. I don't know how it got inside him but these are the "dreams" that he's talking about... which have Christina in them. You will notice these images everytime he exits the Source Code.

In the end of the film they end up spending the day together by skipping work. Christina takes him here:

[image]

Colter asks "Do you believe in fate". He asks this because she's brought him to the place where he dreamed about seeing her. The relevance of that dialogue is this ending that makes his vivid dreams a virtual reality.